# django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: django_session

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-forms

Premise: I'm a starter[Plz be kind and patient]
When i try to run commands in the terminal like:

```
python manage.py makemigrations audioma_manager
```

or

```
python manage.py runserver
```

or

```
python manage.py migrate
```

or

```
python manage.py --run-syncdb
```

**where**
audioma_manager is the name of my project

*I tried also with the name of my app*

I get this excetion code, I searched lots on the net but any kind of solution works with my problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\39371\AudioManVenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\39371\AudioManVenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 423, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: django_session

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\39371\AudioManVenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\39371\AudioManVenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\39371\AudioManVenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\39371\AudioManVenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\39371\AudioManVenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\39371\AudioManVenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 75, in handle
    self.check(databases=[database])
  File "C:\Users\39371\AudioManVenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 423, in check
    databases=databases,
  File "C:\Users\39371\AudioManVenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\39371\AudioManVenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\39371\AudioManVenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\39371\AudioManVenv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 412, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\39371\AudioManVenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\39371\AudioManVenv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 598, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\39371\AudioManVenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\39371\AudioManVenv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 591, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\39371\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\39371\audioma_manager\audioma_manager\urls.py", line 20, in <module>
    path('transcription_form/', include('transcription_form.urls')),
  File "C:\Users\39371\AudioManVenv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\39371\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\39371\audioma_manager\transcription_form\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .views import upload
  File "C:\Users\39371\audioma_manager\transcription_form\views.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .forms import UploadForm
  File "C:\Users\39371\audioma_manager\transcription_form\forms.py", line 5, in <module>
    source_choice=GetAPISources.call_api(GetAPISources,endpoint='sources')
  File "C:\Users\39371\audioma_manager\transcription_form\client_transcpition_api.py", line 48, in call_api
    session_stored = s.load()
  File "C:\Users\39371\AudioManVenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\db.py", line 43, in load
    s = self._get_session_from_db()
  File "C:\Users\39371\AudioManVenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\db.py", line 34, in _get_session_from_db
    expire_date__gt=timezone.now()
  File "C:\Users\39371\AudioManVenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\39371\AudioManVenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 431, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "C:\Users\39371\AudioManVenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 262, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\39371\AudioManVenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1324, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\39371\AudioManVenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 51, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "C:\Users\39371\AudioManVenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1175, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\39371\AudioManVenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\39371\AudioManVenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\39371\AudioManVenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\39371\AudioManVenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\39371\AudioManVenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\39371\AudioManVenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\39371\AudioManVenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 423, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: django_session
```

This is my setting file( I'm using django-environ to keep secret some variables):

```
import environ
import os
from pathlib import Path

env = environ.Env(
    # set casting, default value
    DEBUG=(bool, False)
)
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="audioma_manager.settings"
# Set the project base directory
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent 

# Take environment variables from .env file
environ.Env.read_env(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '.env'))

# False if not in os.environ because of casting above
DEBUG = env('DEBUG')

# Raises Django's ImproperlyConfigured
# exception if SECRET_KEY not in os.environ
SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY')

# Parse database connection url strings
# like psql://user:pass@127.0.0.1:8458/db
#For production
#DATABASES = {
    # read os.environ['DATABASE_URL'] and raises
    # ImproperlyConfigured exception if not found
    #
    # The db() method is an alias for db_url().
    'default': env.db(),

    # read os.environ['SQLITE_URL']
    #'extra': env.db_url(
        #'SQLITE_URL',
        #default='sqlite:///tmp/my-tmp-sqlite.db'
  # )
#}

CACHES = {
    # Read os.environ['CACHE_URL'] and raises
    # ImproperlyConfigured exception if not found.
    #
    # The cache() method is an alias for cache_url().
    'default': env.cache(),

 #instance of sensibile data from .env file
}
API_URL= {
    env('API_URL')
    }
API_VERSION={
    env('API_VERSION')
    }
API_USERNAME={
    env('API_USERNAME')
    }
API_PASSWORD={
    env('API_PASSWORD')
    }
API_ENDPOINT_SOURCES={
    env('API_ENDPOINT_SOURCES')
}
DEFAULT_DIR_PATH={
    env('DEFAULT_DIR_PATH')
    }
DEFAULT_NAME_FILE_PATTERN={
    env('DEFAULT_NAME_FILE_PATTERN')
    }
API_ENDPOINT_LOGIN={
    env('API_ENDPOINT_LOGIN')
}




# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent



# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'transcription_form',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework'
    
    
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware'
    
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'audioma_manager.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'audioma_manager.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases
#Local db for tests
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME':  BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
        'USER': 'USER',
        'PASSWORD': 'PASS',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': 3306
    }
    
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename':  '\\Users\\39371\\audioma_manager\\audioma_manager\\logs\\debug.log',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'transcription_form.client_transcription_api': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'INFO'
        
        },
    },
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'http://localhost:8080',
)
```

My client:

```
from audioma_manager.settings import API_ENDPOINT_LOGIN, API_PASSWORD, API_URL, API_USERNAME, API_VERSION
from django.contrib.sessions.backends.db import SessionStore
import requests
from requests.structures import CaseInsensitiveDict

#class API management
class GetAPISources:
    #authentication to aziendal api
    def auth_api(self):
        
        url = API_URL + API_VERSION + API_ENDPOINT_LOGIN
        
        auth_email = API_USERNAME
        
        auth_password = API_PASSWORD
        
        list_of_auth = [auth_email,auth_password]
        
        response= requests.post(url,list_of_auth)
        
        if response.status_code==400:
            
        #manage exception code; return null
            
            return False
        
        token=response['token']
        
         #instance of SessionStore
         
        s=SessionStore()
        
        s['auth_token']=token
        
       # saves the current token
        
        s.save()
        
       
    #implement a method who calls API endpoint  from InfojuiceAPi with representation=1
    
    def call_api(self,endpoint):
        
        api_repr='&representation=1'
        
        s=SessionStore()
        
        session_stored = s.load()
        
        auth_token=session_stored['auth_token']
        
        
        #used endpoint so i can customize the type of endpoint everytime i call the function
        #example--> endpoint='/sources' ; endpoint='/customers'
        
        url = API_URL + API_VERSION + endpoint + api_repr
        
        headers = CaseInsensitiveDict()
        headers["Accept"]="application/json"
        headers["Authorization"]="token " + auth_token

        response= requests.get(url,headers=headers)
        
        
        if response.status_code==401:
           self.auth_api()
           self.call_api(endpoint)

        return response
```

My Model:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Transcription(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=10000)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, name='created_at')
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, name='updated_at')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.file_name
```

My Form:

```
from django import forms
from .client_transcpition_api import GetAPISources


source_choice=GetAPISources.call_api(GetAPISources,endpoint='sources')

class UploadForm(forms.Form):        
    lang = forms.CharField(label='Lingua', max_length=100, help_text = "Inserisci la lingua del contenuto")
    source = forms.CharField(label='Fonte', help_text = "Seleziona la fonte del contenuto" , widget=forms.Select(choices=source_choice))
    data = forms.DateField(label='data', help_text = "Seleziona la data del contenuto ", max_length=100)
    time = forms.TimeField(label='ora', help_text = "Seleziona l' orario del contenuto", max_length=100)
    extension = forms.CharField(label='estensione', help_text = "Seleziona l'estensione del contenuto", max_length=100)
    file = forms.FileField(label='file da caricare', help_text = "Seleziona il file da mandare in trascrizione")
```

My views:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import UploadForm

def upload(request):
    
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = UploadForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
          
            # redirect to a new URL:
            #this url is only temp, evaluate better how to do
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
        else:
            form = upload()
    return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form': form})
```

My template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% Block Content %}
<h2>Upload</h2>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/foo/">

    <!-- we need to use this token bc Django makes security controls and requires this token 
    to be recognize as  trust source of code  -->
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
    <input type="file" name="recupero">
    <button type="submit">Invio</button>

</form>
```

In my project I want to:

1)Create repositories, new Django project and first commit.

2)Install Django Environ to upload configurations via .env files.
The configuration must allow you to configure:
authentication to Aziendal API (URL, version, username, password)
path directory for saving the new file to be transcribed
filename pattern (with placeholder for replacing the various components, such as date, source name, title, language, time)

3)Create the Transcription model to save information about content sent in transcription.
Scheme:
ID
file_name Method (String)
created_at (Datetime)
updated_at (Datetime)

4)
Implement a mini client to Aziendal API for THE GET retrieval of sources filtered by name and with the query parameter for rapresentation retrieval.
Use the authentication configured in the configuration file.

5)
Implement a page with a form to load a new transcript with the following fields:
date (date)
source (select sources taken from API)
language (select taken from the configuration)
title
possible profile (optional)

Plz help a young starter.
If u need some source code of my project, just ask:)
Thx for help
xoxo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most pressing problem here is that you're doing a database call at import time by trying to load a session via

```
  File "C:\Users\39371\audioma_manager\transcription_form\forms.py", line 5, in <module>
    source_choice=GetAPISources.call_api(GetAPISources,endpoint='sources')
  File "C:\Users\39371\audioma_manager\transcription_form\client_transcpition_api.py", line 48, in call_api
    session_stored = s.load()
  File "C:\Users\39371\AudioManVenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\db.py", line 43, in load
    s = self._get_session_from_db()
```

which is a big no-no in Django and leads to a chicken-and-egg problem:

- you need to make migrations and run migrations to create database tables
- Django needs to be able to import your app to do so
- your app tries to do a database query from an as-of-yet-nonexistent table (since it's not been migrated yet).

You'll need to do that `source_choice` at e.g. `__init__` time for the form, not at import time.

For the time being, you can replace the `source_choice=...` line with just `source_choice=[]` – you won't have any sources to choose from, but you can get your migrations running.

That aside, that session-related code looks strange, *especially* since you're trying to do so outside of a request context. There will be no valid session to load in that case, since there is no request either. I think you may be confusing Django sessions with whatever the API you're using requires.

Comment: As this answer says, commenting out the parts of my code that were importing and retrieving these as-of-yet nonexistent tables then running the `python manage.py makemigrations` command worked. Thanks.